# Matlab Neutron image reconstructions

Tags: matlab

I am trying to reconstruct an image using the projections from the Neutron image scanner. I am using the following code. I am not able to obtain a meaningful reconstructed image.

Can anybody advise me on where I am going wrong.

much appreciated,
Vani

```
filename = strcat(' Z:\NIST_Data\2016\SEPT\example reconstructed\carboxylic\carboxylic reconstructed part 3\Coral\',srcFiles(i).name);
I=imread(filename);
    P = im2double(I);
if i == 1
 array3d = P;
else
 array3d = cat(3, array3d, P);
end
end

num = size(array3d,3);
 for p = 1:num

    PR = double(squeeze(array3d(p,:,:)));


[L,C]=size(PR); 
w = [-pi : (2*pi)/L : pi-(2*pi)/L]; 
Filt = abs(sin(w));
 Filt = Filt(1:463); 
for i = 1:C,
 IMG = fft(PR(:,i)); 
end
FiltIMG = IMG*Filt; %FiltIMG = filter (b, a, IMG); 
% Remove any remaining imaginary parts 
FIL = real(FiltIMG);


% filter the projections
%filtPR = projfilter(PR);
%filtPR = filterplus(PR);
filtPR = FIL;

THETA=0:180;
% figure out how big our picture is going to be.
n = size(filtPR,1);
sideSize = n;

% convert THETA to radians
th = (pi/180)*THETA;

% set up the image
m = length(THETA); 
BPI = zeros(sideSize,sideSize);

% find the middle index of the projections
midindex = (n+1)/2;

% set up x and y matrices
x = 1:sideSize;
y = 1:sideSize;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
xpr = X - (sideSize+1)/2;
ypr = Y - (sideSize+1)/2;

% loop over each projection
%figure
%colormap(jet)
%M = moviein(m);
for i = 1:m
    tic
    disp(['On angle ', num2str(THETA(i))]);

    % figure out which projections to add to which spots
    filtIndex = round(midindex + xpr*sin(th(i)) - ypr*cos(th(i)));

    % if we are "in bounds" then add the point
    BPIa = zeros(sideSize,sideSize);
    spota = find((filtIndex > 0) & (filtIndex <= n));
    newfiltIndex = filtIndex(spota);
    BPIa(spota) = filtPR(newfiltIndex(:),i);
    %keyboard 
    BPI = BPI + BPIa; 

    toc

    %imagesc(BPI)
    %M(:,i) = getframe;
    %figure(2)
    %plot(filtPR(:,i));
    %keyboard
end

BPI = BPI./m;
h=figure
imagesc(BPI)
saveas(h,sprintf('filtsli-FIG%d.tif',p));end
```

Comment: It is not possible to say what is wrong. You didn't provide your input datas, what is the actual result, what is the expected result. what are the errors... you should have a look at [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first.

Comment: Dear marcoresk, Apologies.